# Mesh error quantification using error norm for a sharp logistic function

Tags: error-estimation, mesh

Consider the following logistic function in 1D for the domain $0$ to $1$.

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-50(x-0.5))} $$

Let's say I resolve this on two meshes:

- first with 11 equispaced points (0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ... 1.0)
- second with 101 equispaced points (0.0, 0.01, 0.02, ... 1.0)

The plots for the two meshes look like this (blue is first, green is second):

[image]

How do I compute the error norm for the two meshes? I don't know if L2 norm is the best choice but let's say it is. In that case, the discrete version of the L2 norm is usually stated as follows:

$$ ||\mathrm{error}||_{2}
^{2} = h \sum_{i} |f_{i,\mathrm{ref}} - f_{i,h}|^2 $$

Where $f_{i,h}$ is function value for a given mesh at mesh point $i$, and $f_{i,\mathrm{ref}}$ is the value of the analytical function used as a reference.

However this will produce zero error norm for both cases, since the function evaluated at the mesh points is exact, i.e., it comes directly from the analytical expression. But we can clearly see in the plot that it's a wrong answer for the mesh with 11 points, i.e., error should be non-zero around the middle of the domain, resulting in a non-zero error norm. The zero-error answer is wrong for 101 points too but in the plot the error is not very visible (but it's still there, due to discretization/sampling). In other words, the second mesh has reduced the error compared to the first mesh. (what I described is beginner stuff; just putting things in context).

For correct error computation, a possible alternative is to compute the norm through quadrature. But before we even think about quadrature, we need to compute the error function itself. But how do we do that? Do we use a high resolution mesh (like 1001, or 10001 points) where we resolve $f_{i,\mathrm{ref}}$ as well as interpolate $f_{i,h}$ (say we use linear interpolation)? but this feels very sloppy/adhoc. Is there a better, more systematic way?

(I'm just trying to find out what are the "standard" ways of doing such error analysis for mesh resolution, such that I can show that the error in the second case goes down compared to that in the first case. Any tips for doing similar analysis in 2D on unstructured meshes would also be highly appreciated).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but Did you try the standard error formula for linear interpolation piecewise? (See proposition 1.2 in [this pdf](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0uYjHnpjXAhWBKcAKHRLnAZUQFggxMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783642332869-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1368510-p174611366&usg=AOvVaw09efgmkkG7kfBEKEbjBfxc) ) The formula relate the estimate to $h^4$, and the second derivate of $f$ (you have $f$ so you can estimate the required norm)

Comment: I am not familiar with the proposition in the document you shared (probably something like that is what I'm looking for). I'll try to understand it but it will take time. Do you think this pdf chapter has enough details that can let me do simple/standard meshing error analysis on an analytical function?

Comment: This kind of arguments, generally, are present in entry level course of numerical analysis, so if your goal is to work over mesh error I suggest to look this argument. The above pdf is an example, but there are a lot of books. With this back ground, for example, you easy understand that calculate the error between the function and the interpolation in the mesh points has no much sense because when you built the interpolation function you force it to be equals the real function over the mesh.

Comment: Considering your case roughly speaking we can tell that the second mesh is 100 times better than the first (if you see the norm error and not the square norm).

Comment: It may not make much sence because I presented the problem in 1D and oversimiplified form. But if it is 2D, and my second mesh was generated from an adaptive meshing technique (that I'm trying to publish) then it makes all the sense to do this error analysis. Furthermore, this is the right-hand-side (or input) to a PDE, and I have to show that if input error reduces, output error reduces as a result. In that case it makes a world of sense don't you think?

Comment: Maybe is better go to chat, anyway I understand that you are calculating the error between the original function and the interpolation function using only the mesh points. If you do so you will obtain always zero (1D, 2D), because you are using only the interpolation points, and is for this reason is not very meaningful. In my opinion a better approach is try to use estimate theorems that permit to make comparisons among meshes, as I made above, similar estimate there is also for FEM for example, so maybe there are also for your specific case.  continue....

Comment: Or use a set of points with empty intersection with the meshes. In this way you obtain error values different from zero, because in these points the the interpolation function is not forced to be equal the original fucntion. It is natural that if exist error theorem the values will respect the estimates and you have a "double check".

Comment: @MauroVanzetto I'm up for chat, but I don't know how (what website or app). Kindly let me know how you prefer to chat and I'll be available. Thanks.

Comment: I make the chat room, and invite you

Comment: @MauroVanzetto Just wanted to let you know that I read your pdf and it does not answer my question. I have thought about my problem a little more and have come up with some ideas. Essentially if you can compute definite integral symbolically between two adjacent mesh points then computing the error norm is easy. If the integration is intractable, then you have to compute a very high resolution quadrature between every two adjacent mesh points (as far as I can tell). (In both cases have to keep "zero crossings" in mind, to integrate modulus correctly).

Comment: Actually I slightly take my word back. Calculating the integral of the modulus of an analytical function is not as straightforward as calculating the integral of the function itself. Therefore we're back to square one: high-resolution quadrature coupled with detection of zero crossings.